# How to check if an element is overlapping other elements?

Tags: javascript, boundary

I have two div elements. Each of them have 450px width and height. How do I check if the first div is overlapping the second div?

I've tried to use javascript hittest, but it's a little bit complicated. Since I'm trying to find out how it actually work, I would like to get started with a simpler code.

I found out that I can use **.getClientRects** to get the boundary of an element, but I'm not exactly sure how to compare boundaries.

Please advise me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection can you see if this helps you out.

Comment: So what you're asking is that given an array of bounding rectangles, how do you determine which ones overlap?

Comment: Just curious why it marked as duplicated since there is no jQuery reference in OP.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Something like this for `rect1` and `rect2` retrieved via [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect):

```
var overlap = !(rect1.right < rect2.left || 
                rect1.left > rect2.right || 
                rect1.bottom < rect2.top || 
                rect1.top > rect2.bottom)
```

Explain: if one or more expressions in the parenthese are `true`, there's no overlapping. If all are `false`, there must be an overlapping.

Comment: Just figured out that this only works if both elements are currently visible - a shame!

Comment: Would switching the logic to use `&&` give a tiny performance boost on occasions when they don't overlap?

Comment: Removing the negation and turning the checks around makes the code faster & easier to reason about. Also, with the current check the edges are allowed to touch instead of overlapping. The difference between `<` & `<=`.

Comment: in firefox with 2 fixed elements is not working

Comment: what if some elements are rotated?
this method does not work for rotated elements. any new idea!?

Answer (score 23):

Here's something I made some days ago: **https://gist.github.com/yckart/7177551**

```
var AABB = {
  collide: function (el1, el2) {
    var rect1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rect2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();

    return !(
      rect1.top > rect2.bottom ||
      rect1.right < rect2.left ||
      rect1.bottom < rect2.top ||
      rect1.left > rect2.right
    );
  },

  inside: function (el1, el2) {
    var rect1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rect2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
      ((rect2.top <= rect1.top) && (rect1.top <= rect2.bottom)) &&
      ((rect2.top <= rect1.bottom) && (rect1.bottom <= rect2.bottom)) &&
      ((rect2.left <= rect1.left) && (rect1.left <= rect2.right)) &&
      ((rect2.left <= rect1.right) && (rect1.right <= rect2.right))
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Inside can be simplified to: `rect1.top <= rect2.bottom && rect1.bottom >= rect2.top && rect1.left <= rect2.right && rect1.right >= rect2.left`

Comment: but what about those elements are rotated ?
refer link http://jsfiddle.net/zch7uLr3/3/
I m facing issue in rotated elements

Answer (score 1):

element.getBoundingClientRect() is quiet good in modern browsers, delivers a bounding relative to the screen. look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) Than test if the bounding boxes overlap, that is simple geometry...

oh excuse me... found your edit too late...

Comment: What about if element is rotated ? how can we find out that rotated element/div not overlapping with another element/div ? refer link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76505905/how-verify-rotated-div-is-overllapping-with-another-div

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer earlier than version 8, the returned [TextRectangle](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgupwlp.php) object contains the coordinates in physical pixel size, while from version 8, it contains the coordinates in logical pixel size.

If you need the bounding rectangle of the entire element, use the [getBoundingClientRect](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmcrrn.php) method.