# Detect element if over another element via using CSS3 Transform

Tags: jquery, css, transform, detect

Any easy way to detect element if its over another element ?

I'm using CSS3 transform to move a element. ([because](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/))

Example :
- All element size 10x10 pixels

- Element#A `transform : translate(170px, 180px)` <-- This element can controll for moving
- Element#B `transform : translate(200px, 200px)`

How to detect is element#A over some element ?

**My full demo with jQuery element controller :** http://jsfiddle.net/ndZj5/

```
var over = false;
// do something with `over` to `true` to detect this...
if(!over) {
  my.css('transform','translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px)');
}
```

Take a tour on my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ndZj5/) , press keyboard arrows to controll

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066870/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-overlapping-other-elements as it might be easier using [`.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `offset` to get the `position` of the moved object and compare it with the "blocks".

I've setup in my demonstration the "blocks" to change to blue when they are overlayed. But you can do whatever you want.

Also you were creating an overhead with your `setInterval`. I've moved it to the `keyup` event handler.

Further I recommend you to store the position of the "blocks" in an `array` if they are static elements and access them when needed.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ndZj5/1/)

```
var objTop = my.offset().top,
    objLeft = my.offset().left,
    objWidth = my.width(),
    objHeight = my.height();            

$('.fixed').each(function(e){
    var self = $(this),
        selfLeft = self.offset().left,
        selfTop = self.offset().top,
        selfWidth = self.width(),
        selfHeight = self.height();

    self.css('background','black');                 

    if((objLeft + objWidth) > selfLeft && objLeft < (selfLeft + selfWidth) && (objTop + objHeight) > selfTop && objTop < (selfTop + selfHeight)){
        self.css('background','blue');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much , what about detect 100 objs ?

Comment: This will also work for 100 objects although it won't work very fast. As I said, I recommend you to store the position of the fixed elements in an array (or perhaps in a json file which would be better in this case) an access them when needed.

Comment: @enyce12 Can you add what this would look like in Pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to see the position of an element relative to the document.  This *does* take into account `translate`.  You can get the coordinates of the rectangle with `.offset` and then `.offset.left + width` / `.offset.top + height`.  Then you can easily check for an overlap.