# When a dragged element touches other element / leave other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I have a element (`#dot`) which can be dragged. The dragged element (`#dot`) is just allowed to be in multiple (`.way`)s but when (`#dot`) leaves this element then  a function should start (for now a alert is enough). I have search on stackoverflow and on other pages but I dont find out somethings like this.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SJam/13/)**

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#dot').draggable({
    containment: "#world",
  });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="world">
    <div id="dot"></div>
    <div class="way">
    </div>
</div>
```

For now an alert is enough...

My question is, how can i check if the element touches on other element?

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you researched any material about collision detection? And BTW - why don't you use the HTML5 `Canvas`?

Comment: What's your question???

Comment: I want about this function but the function starts when i hover the `id="world"`.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection) a dup?

Comment: You can use `containment: ".way"`, then you will only be able to drag the dot in the 'white' area, but it still won't detect actual collisions.

Comment: what do you mean by "when the first Element touches the place"? when dragged item is hovered over, or dropped onto..?

Comment: @TJ I want say when the droped elemtent `#dot` touches `#world`

Comment: @KamilT i know but there should be a alert function when the `#dot` leaves the white area

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer:

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/yorohimi/4

Seems like you can use jQuery draggable and droppable for this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#dot').draggable();
  $('.way').droppable({
    accept:'#dot',
    tolerance:'fit',        
    over:function(event,ui){
      $('p').text('moved inside way');
      $('#world').removeClass('green');
    },
    out:function(event,ui){
      $('p').text('moved outside way');
      $('#world').addClass('green');
    }
  });  
});
```

The key is to use `tolerance:fit` here in droppable. Whenever `#dot` touches `#world` the color of `#world` is changed for visual feedback.

Following method will work only for single `.way`.
You can compare the position using `getBoundingClientRect` method and execute your code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9SJam/4/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dot').draggable({
        axis: "y",
        containment: "#world",
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            drag_handler($(ui.helper));
        }
    });
});

function drag_handler(elem) {
    var p = elem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var P = $('.way')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if ((P.top > p.top) || (P.bottom < p.bottom)) {
        console.log('touched');
        $('#world').addClass('color');//For visual feedback
    } else {
        $('#world').removeClass('color'); //For visual feedback
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you are looking for x axis also, you can also compare right,left position.

Comment: no i wont, i've already hear something like that but your solution is far better

Comment: I've a question: Whats when i have more then one `.way`? http://jsfiddle.net/9SJam/8/ and when i leave the `.way` on the right side then the function dont start

Comment: That's what I said in earlier comment. If you need to check on x axis also, then you will have to compare the right and left position too just like bottom and top positions are compared in the code. In case of multiple .way, just loop through all .way

Comment: oh, my false I misunderstood you before. So what I have to do. This doesnt work jsfiddle.net/9SJam/11

Comment: You can further take help from this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661108/detect-element-if-over-another-element-via-using-css3-transform 
I believe this is what you may need further

Comment: do you see my fiddle file?

Comment: Yes I did. In short you want to detect when your element is over a specific element. The link which I mentioned does exactly that. Just give a try

Comment: I did not quite understand what I need to do exactly. And how can it several `.way` use?

Comment: So i've find out to set the right and left side, so i have even tried to use a loop for multiple classes but this wont work...

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `#world` as droppable, then you can use it's  [over](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over) event to trigger your function, which is triggered when an accepted draggable is dragged over the droppable.

something like

```
$( "#world" ).droppable({
 over: function() {
      // Your logic
      }
});
```