# Detect if fixed element is over a div

Tags: jquery

How does one detect when a fixed element is over a div? In this case when the anchor is over `.images`:

```js
var fixedElement = $('a'),
    images = $('.images'),
    imagesTop = images.offset().top,
    imagesLeft = images.offset().left,
    imagesWidth = images.width(),
    imagesHeight = images.height();            

if(`fixedElement` is over `images`) {
    fixedElement.addClass('active');
}
```

```css
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #aaa;
}
.images {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>Hello world</a>
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200">
</div>
```

Came across [Detect element if over another element via using CSS3 Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661108/detect-element-if-over-another-element-via-using-css3-transform) but it looks way too complicated.

**UPDATE**: See kthornbloom's comment

Comment: What is your end goal? Unless I'm misunderstanding, this type of thing is typically done by comparing measurements. i.e. how far down you've scrolled + the anchor height versus the position of your .images div.

Comment: Hello! My goal is to add a class to the anchor once it's over the div in question.

Comment: Ok, here's some code I made awhile back that works by those measurements I was talking about. In this example, it uses slideUp and slideDown, but you could easily change it to addClass and removeClass. http://jsfiddle.net/euDb8/7/  Just posting this as a comment since it doesn't answer your question how it was asked.

Comment: try [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint)