# Avoid anchor tags stoping propagation of clicks

Tags: javascript, html, events

I found that a tags stop events from propagating down in the DOM. Take this example: if you click the red button, a text should log, but if you press where they overlap, you'll only get the link behaviour. **¿Is there any way to force the propagation of the event to the bottom?**

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("btn clicked");
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
a {
  background: rgba(0, 200, 100, 0.3);
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Press me</div>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

It seems that the snippet is preventing the link from firing, but test it here and you'll see it: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/wMNKOG

Comment: The anchor tag is over lapping the div element so obviously if you click where the anchor tag is it will navigate... I'm not sure what it is you're looking for?

Comment: can't you set `z-index:-1` in a tag..it will work like you want

Comment: @NewToJS yes, but note it will open in a new window, it has target _blank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720 visit this

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha I'm sorry but I don't think it is a matter of bubling or capturing, if instead of a link it was a div it would work as expected

Comment: you can check by whether it is overlapping or not by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066870/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-overlapping-other-elements ..if it gives true then do both task in js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put `a` inside your `.btn`.

```
<div class="btn">
    Press me
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible in the real world problem, although it is in this example. Are you saying that this would only work for parent-child elements but not for siblings overlaping by absolute positioning?

Comment: as a solution, as all events bubbles to the top, just add event handler in wrapper that will contains your button and a link. In that case, if you click whatever button or link event will bubbles and event will be catched. That called event delegation.

Comment: could you give an example?