# How to tell if two elements are touching

Tags: javascript, html

Through JavaScript, I want to find out how to find whether a span and a button are touching. I saw something, Element.getBoundingClientRect(). If that is the way to do it, how do I properly do it?

I've already attempted to use
      Element.getBoundingClientRect()
but most likely not used it properly.

```
  var span1 = document.getElementById("mySpan")
  var button = document.getElementById("myButton")
  if(touches(span1, button)){
   ...
   }
```

Comment: Do you mean touching like `<tag><second-tag>` or touching as in they are only 1 pixel apart on the display?

Comment: @Intervalia on the display

Comment: Could you add HTML code example of the touching elements.

Comment: "mySpan" and "myButton" are display block or display inline ?

Comment: what about if screen redim place those element on different lines ?

Comment: what about margin of elements ?

Comment: Possible duplicate in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks if (inline elements) a `span` element and `button` element are next to each other.

```js
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]

if(touches(span, btn)){
  console.log('touching!')
}

function touches(span, btn) {
   var rect1 = span.getBoundingClientRect();
   var rect2 = btn.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (rect1.right == rect2.left) {
     return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Span</span><button>Btn</button>
```

---

As for block elements such as `div` elements

```js
var div1 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
var div2 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1]

if(touches(div1, div2)){
  console.log('Touching!')
}

function touches(div1, div2) {
  var rect1 = div1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var rect2 = div2.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (rect1.bottom == rect2.top) {
      return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Div 1</div><div>Div 2</div>
```

Comment: It works, but unfortunately it gave me another bug with the (for lack of better word) hitboxes of <span> elements. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the second response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection), with pure Javascript, `getBoundingClientRect()` is a correct approach.

Take a look at the code below, this should do the work:

```
function touches(a, b) {
  var aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
  var bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();

  return !(
      ((aRect.top + aRect.height) < (bRect.top)) ||
      (aRect.top > (bRect.top + bRect.height)) ||
      ((aRect.left + aRect.width) < bRect.left) ||
      (aRect.left > (bRect.left + bRect.width))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getBoundingClientRect` is what you want.

The code below is a simple example. You may need to add additional logic.

```js
var span1 = document.getElementById("mySpan")
var button = document.getElementById("myButton")
var clickMe = document.getElementById("clickMe")
var outer = document.getElementById("outer")

function touches(el1, el2) {
  const r1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const r2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  console.log(r1.right, r2.left);
  
  if (r2.left - r1.right < 1) {
    console.log('touching');
  }
  else {
    console.log('not touching');
  }
}

touches(span1, button);

clickMe.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outer.classList.toggle('touch');
  setTimeout(() => {
    touches(span1, button);
  },0);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  font: 14px Tahoma;
  position: relative;
}

#mySpan {
  background-color: red;
}

.touch #myButton {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <span id="mySpan">span</span>
  <button id="myButton">Button</button>
  <hr/>
  <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the client rect of the two elements:

```
var span1 = document.getElementById("mySpan");
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");

var rect1 = span1.getBoundingClientRect();
var rect2 = button.getBoundingClientRect();

var overlap = (rect1.right == rect2.left ||  // right to left touching
rect1.left == rect2.right ||                 // left to right touching
rect1.bottom == rect2.top ||                 // bottom to top touching
rect1.top == rect2.bottom)                   // top to bottom touching

if(overlap){
  // ... do your stuff
}
```

if one or more expressions in the parenthese are true, there's touching. If all are false, there must be an overlapping or not touching.

[How to check if an element is overlapping other elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066870/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-overlapping-other-elements)

adapted from there...