# Detect overlapping elements

Tags: html, typescript, overlay, collision-detection, overlap

I have a few draggable divs that have the same parent.
How would I get an array of divs that are touching anoter specified div?

Eg:

```
let item1:HTMLDivElement;

let touchingDivs:HTMLDivElement[] = getTouchingDivs(item1);
```

I've tried something like

```js
var overlap = !(rect1.right < rect2.left ||rect1.left > rect2.right ||rect1.bottom < rect2.top || rect1.top > rect2.bottom)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12067046/20522485

but it wouldn't work because I do not know which 2 identified elements will be touching with each other

Answer (score 0):

use function `getTouchingDivs(item1)`. This function compares the sibling divs and rectangles of item1. After this use `getBoundingClientRect()` function which return array of divs based on their position and sizes which are overlapping with item1. Here is the example:

```
function getTouchingDivs(item) {
    let touchingDivs = [];
    let itemRect = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    let siblingDivs = item.parentNode.children;

    for (let div of siblingDivs) {
        if (div !== item) {
            let divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
            let overlap = !(itemRect.right < divRect.left || itemRect.left > divRect.right || itemRect.bottom < divRect.top || itemRect.top > divRect.bottom);
            if (overlap) {
                touchingDivs.push(div);
            }
        }
    }
    return touchingDivs;
}

let item1 = document.getElementById("yourDivId"); // Replace with your div's ID
let touchingDivs = getTouchingDivs(item1);
```